# Wallpapers folder issues

Tags: unity, desktop-background

If I set an image as my desktop background, Ubuntu creates a Wallpapers folder in my Pictures folder and puts that image there. If I switch to another wallpaper, it does the same thing, so both images are in the Wallpapers folder. Then if I choose the first image again, it will attempt to save it to the folder and then come up with a message asking if I want to overwrite it.

Is this normal? Why does it act this way? Shouldn't it be easier to switch back and forth between wallpaper images without having duplicate files or popups asking about overwriting? Why does it even save images there in the first place?

Comment: What version of ubuntu are you running? What desktop are you running? The default location for wallpapers in Ubuntu 16.10 Unity desktop is  /usr/share/backgrounds/

Comment: How are you setting it up as a wallpaper? Are you using any software for that?

Comment: @GrannySez 16.10

Comment: @Parto Nope, just right clicking an image and choosing "set as desktop background"

Comment: What desktop are you using (Unity, Gnome, KDE)? They all have different ways of doing things. I would recommend looking at Variety it's a good wallpaper auto-swapper (if you like swapping wallpapers frequently) and you can define where you want wallpapers saved (and I believe setup slide-show type wallpaper based on pics you've saved in a specific location).